# Seemingly odd JSON.parse behaviour in node with double backslashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

A colleague was attempting to parse a json string generated in another system and ran into behavior we were not able to explain. I've replicated the problem with a very small code example here:

```js
// running in node >= 8 (tried both 8 and 12)

const str1 = '{ "test": "path\\test" }';
const str2 = '{ "test": "path\\atest" }';

try {
  console.log('str1:', JSON.parse(str1));
} catch (e) {
  console.log('str1 fail')
}

try {
  console.log('str2:', JSON.parse(str2))
} catch (e) {
  console.log('str2 fail')
}
```

`str1` will successfully parse into the desired format of `{ test: 'path\test' }`
`str2` will fail.

It seems like this will only succeed if the character immediately following `\\` is one of the [valid JavaScript escape characters](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes)

(\t: horizontal tab in the `str1` case)

The intended behavior is to escape the `\\` into a single `\`

Is there an explanation for this behavior? We're stumped and would appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a string literal with two backslashes, those two backslashes will be interpreted as a single literal backslash, Eg, the `.length` of `'\\test'` is 5, not 6.

`JSON.parse` only allows backslashes before characters that *can* be escaped, like `t` (horizontal tab) and `n` (newline). When you have a literal backslash before a character that can't be escaped (like `a`), `JSON.parse` throws an error. (This is unlike Javascript string literals, which *can* have unnecessarily escaped normal characters - eg `const str = '\a'` is equivalent to `'a'`, and doesn't throw an error.) You can see an illustration of what's permitted in JSON [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) - as you can see by the fourth graphic, after a `\`, the only permitted characters are one of `"\/bfnrt`, or `uXXXX`, where each X is a hex digit.

If you wanted the value of the `test` property in the parsed object to be the string `path`, followed by a literal backslash, followed by `test` or `atest`, you'd need to use *four* backslashes when declaring the string literal - first, to have the Javascript interpreter interpret it as two literal backslashes, and second, to have `JSON.parse` interpret the two literal backslashes as a single backslash in the parsed string.

```js
const str1 = '{ "test": "path\\\\test" }';
const str2 = '{ "test": "path\\\\atest" }';

try {
    console.log('str1:', JSON.parse(str1));
} catch (e) {
    console.log('str1 fail')
}

try {
    console.log('str2', JSON.parse(str2))
} catch (e) {
    console.log('str2 fail')
}
```

You can also define string literals with `String.raw` for any single backslash in the string to be interpreted as a single literal backslash (rather than the beginning of an escape sequence):

```js
const str1 = String.raw`{ "test": "path\\test" }`;
const str2 = String.raw`{ "test": "path\\atest" }`;

try {
    console.log('str1:', JSON.parse(str1));
} catch (e) {
    console.log('str1 fail')
}

try {
    console.log('str2', JSON.parse(str2))
} catch (e) {
    console.log('str2 fail')
}
```

Comment: "If you wanted the value of the test property in the parsed object to be the string path, followed by a literal backslash, followed by test or atest, you'd need to use four backslashes when declaring the string literal - first, to have the Javascript interpreter interpret it as two literal backslashes, and second, to have JSON.parse interpret the two literal backslashes as a single backslash in the parsed string."  

Aha! This makes sense now, we were getting tripped up by the fact that it's being interpret twice — thank you for the succinct answer!